# Electric field flux through the cubic with surface density of charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields, gauss-law

first of all I want you to excuse me for my level of English.
I'm doing a homework on Gauss's law, specifically on how to calculate electric flux through a cubic surface. Below I put the complete statement :

> We have a charge distribution formed by a point charge $q = 13 \rm nC$ at the origin of coordinates and a surface density of charge $\sigma = −29 \rm pC/ cm^2$ , flat, infinite, parallel to the $xz-$plane in the coordinate $y = a$, with $a = 7 \rm cm$. We also have a closed surface of cubic form of side $\mathrm L$, centered in the origin.
>
> a) Calculate the value of the electric field flux through the cubic surface with side $\rm L=19 cm$.

[image]

What I know is that according to Gauss's law, we can calculate the flow knowing the charge enclosed by the cube, so Ill be able to resolve this if we had no surface charge density using

> \begin{equation}
>   \Phi=\iint\limits_{\texttt{cube}}\mathbf E\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathrm d\mathbf S=\dfrac{Q}{\varepsilon_0}
> \tag{01}\label{01}  
> \end{equation}

But my question here is, how does this affect to charge inside?
Does this affect at all, if so, how do I calculate the electric field flux through the cubic surface?

Comment: I can't update my answer or provide a new answer to your question since it is closed. But I have my doubts on the answer you accepted . See  my comments on the answer provided by Nyra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can calculate the flux through the surface of the cube, by finding the electric field then calculating the flux through the face of the cube.

**First, calculate the electric field**

the electric field for a point charge is
$$\underline{E}=\frac{Q}{(4\pi\epsilon_0)(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})^3}*(x\widehat{\underline{i}}+y\widehat{\underline{j}}+z\widehat{\underline{k}})$$
and the electric field for a sheet a of charge in the $x$-$z$ plane at $y=a$, is
$$
\underline{E}=
\begin{cases}
 -\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}\widehat{\underline{j}}&\text{if}\, y<a\\
 +\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}\widehat{\underline{j}}&\text{if}\, y>a\\
      0\widehat{\underline{j}}&\text{if}\,y=a
\end{cases}
$$

so the total electric field would be the sum of these two fields.

**Second, calculate the flux**

the electric flux is give by
$$E_{flux}=\int\int _R \underline{E}\cdot dA$$

For this case this becomes, withe the cube face being $c\ge x\ge -c$ and $c\ge y\ge -c$ with $c=\frac{19}{2}$

$$E_{flux}=\int_{-c}^c\int_{-c}^c  (\underline{E}\cdot \widehat{\underline{k}}) dxdy$$

therefore $\underline{E}\cdot \widehat{\underline{k}}$ is
$$\underline{E}\cdot \widehat{\underline{k}}=\frac{Qz}{(4\pi\epsilon_0)(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})^3}$$

so the flux is through the face of the cube at $z=\frac{19}{2}$
$$E_{flux}=\int_{-c}^c\int_{-c}^c  (\frac{Qz}{(4\pi\epsilon_0)(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})^3}) dxdy$$

which is the same flux calculation as is the sheet of charge wasn't there, which we can calculate without using integrals.

**calculating the flux from a point charge in the centre of a cube**

The total flux from the point charge is $\frac{q}{\epsilon_0}$, and this is split through the six faces. Therefore the flux through a face is $\frac{q}{6\epsilon_0}$.

**So** in your question the flux through the face of the cube is $\frac{q}{6\epsilon_0}$

hopefully that helps

Comment: Really, really good explanation, thank you so much

Comment: Since the electric field produced by an infinite sheet of charge is given by

$$\vec E_{s}=\frac{\rho_{s}}{2\epsilon}\vec a_{y}$$ 

where in this case $\vec a_{y}$ is a unit vector on the y-axis, then isn't the electric flux $\phi$ due to the sheet of charge on the side of the cube in question given by

$$\phi=\vec E_{s}A=\frac{\rho_{s}}{2\epsilon}\vec a_{y}L^2$$ In which case shouldn't that be added to the flux produced by the point charge of $$\frac{q}{6\epsilon}$$ For the total electric flux through that side of the cube?

Comment: @BobD, agreed, for the 2 faces that are parallel to the sheet, then the flux isn't $\frac{q}{6\epsilon_0}$. I think for the face at $y=-\frac{L}{2}$, the flux is $\frac{q}{6\epsilon_0}+L^2 \frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0} $, and for the face at $y=\frac{L}{2}$, the flux is $\frac{q}{6\epsilon_0}+L^2 \frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}$

Comment: I don't think this is right. It would be $\dfrac{q}{6\epsilon_0}$  if there was no sheet. But with the presence of a negatively charged sheet, more flux should go through it as field lines terminate on the negative charge after originating from a positive charge. And you also claim that through the face $y=-L/2$, flux would be greater than $\dfrac{q}{6\epsilon_0}$ which clearly shouldn't be the case. Can you make it clear why it doesn't matter whether the sheet is there or not?

Comment: the flux through the face at $y=-\frac{L}{2}$, is less than $\frac{q}{6\epsilon_0}$ as $\sigma<0$

Comment: @Nyra Oh okay, I didn't know you were assuming $\sigma$ with sign. And I thought that $\frac{q}{6\epsilon_0}$ is the value you have written for the face with the sheet, I think the confusion is cleared up now :).

Comment: @Nyra I believe they only wanted to know the flux through one face of the cube

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The flux through the surface has two contributions that can be added: 1. The flux due to the uniform electric field of the infinite sheet of charge and 2. The flux due to the electric field from the point charge at the center.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Bob. Your name came up when I was running queries regarding [this thread on meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13556/getting-a-better-understanding-of-how-and-why-off-topic-homework-like-questions). I suspect this reflects the fact that you're one of the clearest holders of a pro-homework view which isn't currently well represented on Meta. As such I would like to invite you to participate there $-$ every perspective is important.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Sure.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Am I supposed to wait for the invite? How do I start?

Comment: No need for an invite -- Meta works the same as main. The current discussion is [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13556) (with the original discussion [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12568/), which can be revived if appropriate).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Thanks. I started looking at the discussions, but as a late comer I'm not sure how to start contributing from a "pro homework" view, especially since I'm not sure what that means specifically, as I routinely vote to close H&E's but generally I have to be at least the fourth person before it is closed  (not sure why). I do have views, particularly on thresholds, but I not sure how to introduce them as a new comer.